# rethinkDB eq(0) return value is not built-in boolean type?

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-python

Can anyone help me?? 
Why the return value of row['TimeInBucket1'].eq(0) is not True or False???? I

Here is the code in python

```
def map1(row):
    flgTB1 = row['TimeInBucket1'].eq(0)

    return {'nMX1Pop': 0 if flgTB1 else 1 ,
          'meanMX1Pop':0.0 if flgTB1 else row['MX1'],
          'varMX1Pop': 0.0 if flgTB1 else row['MX1']*row['MX1']
          }

cursor = r.db(dbName).table(tableName).map(map1).run(connection)
```

Comment: What is the return value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using Python's `if/else`, which is evaluated on the client.  You need to use `r.branch` to do that on the server (so `r.branch(flgTB1, 0, 1)` instead of `0 if flgTB1 else 1`).

Comment: Thanks, it works. But it is shameful that the query constrains override the language syntax.